# What does an if statement with only a variable evaluate to in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm learning about bash --login and saw that the commands in `/etc/profile` are executed first. In that file:

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Now, I admittedly have a limited understanding of control flow in bash but from my understanding, most of the time what I see put in the if statement is some kind of conditional statement, whether it is `[-a FILENAME]` to check if a file exists or a comparison between strings, usually it evaluates to something.

**In the file, two if statements confuse me:**

`if [ "$PS1" ];` and `if[ "$BASH" ]`

I know that PS1 is a variable for the primary prompt, but that's all that's in the if statement. It's not using -a to check existence or comparing it to something else. My educated guess is that simply putting a variable will evaluate to true if it exists.

My question is *what do these if statements evaluate to and why?*

Comment: In bash, `if` is just checking the exit status of the command is 0(true) or not, important thing is `[` and `]`. read `$ help test` and `$ man test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[ "$var" ]` returns true if the length of `$var` is non-zero.  If `var` is either unset or empty, it returns false.

This is useful:

- `[ "$PS1" ]` will evaluate to true only for *interactive* shells.
- `[ "$BASH" ]` will evaluate to true only if the shell is bash (as opposed to dash, ksh, or zsh, etc.).

#### Examples

Only one of the following evaluates to true:

```
$ unset x; [ "$x" ] && echo yes
$ x=""; [ "$x" ] && echo yes
$ x="a"; [ "$x" ] && echo yes
yes
```

#### Documentation

This is documented both in `man bash` and, as [Glenn Jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) notes, in bash's interactive help system.  For information on the `[` command, type:

```
$ help [
[: [ arg... ]
    Evaluate conditional expression.

    This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last argument must
    be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.
```

The above refers you to `test`.  Run `help test` for much more detail:

```
$ help test | less
```

Scroll through that documentation and one finds:

```
  STRING      True if string is not empty.
```

Comment: This was very helpful and makes the /etc/profile file make a lot more sense to me, thank you!

Comment: bash comes with some builtin documentation. At an interactive bash prompt, type `help [` then `help test` and note this: `STRING      True if string is not empty.`

Answer (score 1):

The code `if [ "$PS1" ];` and `if [ "$BASH" ]` test if the strings `"$PS1"` and `"$BASH"` are empty, and do something if they are; and since the `if [ "$BASH" ]` test has a matching `else` it also does something if `$BASH` is empty.

The long form of the statement might be clearer, but the following are all equivalent:

```
test -n "$PS1"   # returns an exit code of `0` if `$PS1` is not empty, or `1` if not.
```

Shorter:

```
test "$PS1"
```

Shorter:

```
[ -n "$PS1" ]
```

Shortest:

```
[ "$PS1" ]
```

Comment: This may seem like a small detail but, under bash, it is possible for a variable to _exist_ but still be _empty_.  `[ "$var" ]` does not test whether `var`  _exists_.  It tests whether it is _nonempty_.

Comment: @John1024, Thanks, see revised answer.  Which got me thinking about how to test for a variable's existence, in `bash` I came up with `[ "${x@A}" ]`, (where `$x` is a variable that may or may not exist), and found another method [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212192/165517), but a *POSIX* shell version would be better...

Comment: @agc, `test "${x+set}"` relies only on POSIX-guaranteed functionality (search for "Use Alternate Value" in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).